# MarkerView is not showing up using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPandroidchart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for showing line charts in my application.I have added following code to show Marker View, but it isn't showing on

```
private void initializeChart(LineChart chart, String chartName) {
    // Chart view
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    chart.setDescription("");
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(true);
    //chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(color); // left y-axis
    chart.getXAxis().setTextColor(color);

    chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    CustomMarkerView mv = new CustomMarkerView(this.getActivity(), R.layout.marker_view_tv);
    chart.setMarkerView(mv);

    //X axis
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);

    //Y axis
    YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setStartAtZero(false);

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());


    leftAxis.setLabelCount(Constants.KEY_LINE_YAXIS_SCALECOUNT, true);
    ChartItem item = CannonJsonParser.parseCanonJson(act, act.res);
    int maxYVal = pref.getInt(Constants.KEY_YAXIS_VALUE, 0);
    leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(maxYVal);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0);
    setLineData(item, chartName);
    // set data
    chart.setData(lineData);

    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    //animate
    //chart.animateX(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInExpo);
    chart.setDragEnabled(true);
    chart.setScaleXEnabled(true);
    chart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
    chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);
    chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);


}
```

My CustomMarkerView class

```
public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerView {
private TextView tvContent;

public CustomMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);

    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

    if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {

        CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;

        tvContent.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(ce.getHigh(), 0, true));
    } else {

        tvContent.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(e.getVal(), 0, true));
    }
}

@Override
public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
    // this will center the marker-view horizontally
    return -(getWidth() / 2);
}

@Override
public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
    // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
    return -getHeight();
}
```

}

Note: I am using fragment to show charts.

Comment: For some reason in version 3.1.0-alpha, if you're using `ConstraintLayout` with child's (`TextView`?) property as `match_constraint // represented as 0dp`. The marker doesn't even show. Make sure to give it a fixed width or `match_parent`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `MarkerView` is not showing because **you have not highlighted any entry** in your chart. The `MarkerView` is only displayed for entries that are highlighted.

Since you disabled the functionality to highlight entries per tap (by calling `chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false)`), you can only highlight values programmatically, like this:

`chart.highlightValue(...)`

More on that in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

Comment: In addition, if you are using Compose, you might need to setup a data and isHighlightEnabled in your update block

Answer (score 6):

Faced a similar problem. You should call super to refresh markerview.
Example on Kotlin:

```
 class CustomMarkerView(context: Context, layoutResource: Int) : MarkerView(context, layoutResource) {

    override fun refreshContent(e: Entry?, highlight: Highlight?) {
        markerDate.text = e?.data.toString()
        markerValue.text = e?.y.toString()
        super.refreshContent(e, highlight)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.MarkerView;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CandleEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Utils;

/**
 * Custom implementation of the MarkerView.
 *
 * @author Philipp Jahoda
 */
public class MyMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    private TextView tvContent;

    public MyMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    }

    // callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, int dataSetIndex) {

        if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {

            CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;

            tvContent.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(ce.getHigh(), 0, true));
        } else {

            tvContent.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(e.getVal(), 0, true));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getXOffset() {
        // this will center the marker-view horizontally
        return -(getWidth() / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getYOffset() {
        // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
        return -getHeight();
    }
}
```

And in Fragment Class, Add

```
        MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(this.getActivity(),    R.layout.custom_marker_view);

        // set the marker to the chart
        mChart.setMarkerView(mv);
```

May this helpful to you..

Comment: Thanks a lot man !
That was my problem. I have ordered my entries and now it works well

Answer (score 1):

none of the previous answers worked for me, i found that when you fill the entries from higher to lowest in xAxis the marker don't appear and even other bugs may appear, something like this will cause the error

```
int countX = speedTest.size(); 
ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
for (int i = 0; i < speedTests.size(); i++) {
    SpeedTest st = speedTests.get(i);
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(countX,st.getResultFloat()));
    countX--;
}
```

for me, the only way to fix this was to fill the entries in xAxis from lowest to higher, so the next code worked for me after hours of debugging

```
int countX = 0;
ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
for (int i = 0; i < speedTests.size(); i++) {
    SpeedTest st = speedTests.get(i);
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(countX,st.getResultFloat()));
    countX++;
}
```